# ASP.NET MVC3: Call a view and controller of another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

this question is similar to others, but can not find one to solve my problem.

I have several projects, and all used a same view `CommonGridView.cshtml` that is called with "Razor.PartialView". I need to create a new project and that all call then view `CommonGridView.cshtml` from the new project.

I do not if there is the possibility of adding a directory to which to seek the views, and that this route is another project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If those projects are hosted as separate ASP.NET applications it will be difficult to render a view which is not part of the current application. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) which illustrates a custom virtual path provider which would allow you to embed a Razor view into an assembly that you could reuse between multiple ASP.NET MVC applications.